# Не работает запуск приложений в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день. Хочу начать работать с Андроидом. Установил себе Студио, создал шаблонный проект, не вносил в него никаких изменений, не исправлял даже одной линии, однако эмулятор все равно даже не запускается. Я уже успел немало погуглить на эту тему, однако способа решить мою проблему не отыскалось.
Сама ошибка: Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_24 was killed.
Я пробовал вместо этого запусть шаблонный проект на своем собственном телефоне, однако мой аппарат устойчиво не появляется в списке устройств. (Режим разраба я уже включил, если что.)

Я также пытался установить себе ADB Driver, причем не прямо с главного сайта. Однако, установочник samsung_android_usb_driver.exe даже не запускается со следующей ошибкой.

Разумеется, я попытался использовать другой из представленных там установочников, ADBDriverInstaller.exe . Этот вариант требует перезагрузки с определенными параметрами. Только вот незадача, моя клавиатура не работает до момента входа обратно в систему. То есть в меню с выбором способа загрузки через нажатия одной из F-клавиш я могу только перезагрузить компьютер нажатием кнопки на боку системного блока. Соответственно, продолжить и завершить установку не представляется возможным.

Как предложите поступить?

Comment: Что за ОС, версия студии, версия аппарата? И попробуйте на Вашем реальном телефоне изменить тип подключения (зарядка, МТР, РТР), мне помогло.